# Node Mongo connection Error : connection 4 to xxx cluster closed

Tags: node.js, mongodb, lambda, mongoose

I am developing an app using `AWS Lambda - Nodejs` and using `Mongodb` as backend. 
For connecting with Mongodb, I am using nodejs native library `mongodb`.

Issue is, randomly, Mongodb throws error "connection 4 to cluster is closed".

I found some answers on google, but not working out. Like some ask for adding `keepalive` etc.
As suggested, when working with AWS Lambda, save database connection, I adhere to these guidelines.

Here is the snippet of function which connects to Mongodb.

```
var connectToDatabase = function(_callback){

    var options ={
          server: {
                    socketOptions: {keepAlive: 1}
                  },
          poolSize:100,
          replset: {
                    rs_name: 'voila-cluster-shard-0',
                    socketOptions: {keepAlive: 1}
                  }
    }

    MongoClient.connect(url,options,function(error,connection){
      if(error){
        console.log(error)
        _callback(error)
      }
      else{

        client = connection
        _callback(null,client);
      }
  })
}
```

Can someone help me out here.